# Cannot find linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to install the VMware tools in a VMPlayer VM but in a certain point of the installation I need to set the linux-headers path. So I go and try to install it with this command:

```
 apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then I get the error:

```
 Couldnt find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali-amd64'
```

My sources.list file has these sources:

```
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free

 deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main contrib non-free
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
 deb http://http.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

I already did and apt-get update before trying to install the headers. What can I do to download it?

Comment: Did you try apt-get install open-vm-tools?

Comment: Not an infosec question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. If you do a apt-get install linux-headers*, you'll get a list of close matches. Just say 'N' of course. It looks like 4.3 isn't in the list.

Use linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-amd64 instead...

Comment: The version of the headers should mach the version of the kernel!

Comment: For me the trick was to do an "apt-get dist-upgrade" and then restart the system. Once that had been done, your method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at 4.3, upgrade to 4.4 first and download the headers.
update your sources.list with 'gguth' list and run

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y  && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

This should update your system to 4.4.0.. and then you are aligned to the 4.4.0 kali headers.

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade the kernel release version itself instead of trying to install the linux kernel headers for the old version (4.3.0) of the kernel. Perform the following step after updating the kali /etc/apt/sources.list file with the latest version of the Kali rolling repository:

```
sudo apt-get update # this pulls the latest packages list from the kali sources repo
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade # when installing this, you would see the latest kernel    
                             # image in the list of packages to be installed,something
                             # like" linux-image-4.5.0-kali1-amd64"
reboot # MOST IMPORTANT STEP! make sure you reboot the machine via this cmd OR 
                             # shutdown, restart forcefully after completing prev cmds
uname -r # check that the kernel release has updated =)
```

Good luck!